# How do you remove the %20 from url parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, url, parameter-passing, url-parameters

I'm trying to go to a php page after a search is executed and append the url with a variable which is the value of a searched li element. The value is a users full name which includes a space, I would like to remove the %20 encoding from the parameter, I've tried using the replace function, and the trim function to no avail, you can see this in my commented code.

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){ 
           $('#name').val($(this).text());  
           var user = document.getElementById("name").value;
/*
           user.replace("%20", " ")
           user = encodeURIComponent(user.trim())
           var url = 'newUser.php?users='+x+'',
        vars = {};
    url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
         key = decodeURIComponent(key);
         value = decodeURIComponent(value);
         vars[key] = value;
    });
            var varsString = JSON.stringify(vars);

            var testUser = varsString.value;

                        alert(user.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));
                        user = user.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
*/
          location.href = 'newUser.php?users='+user+'';

           $('#nameList').fadeOut();  




      });
```

Comment: Try: `user = user.replace(/\s/g, '')` or `user = user.split(' ').join()`

Comment: Is PHP related? The `%20` is the url encoded value for a space, why not have it?

Comment: Agree with @user3783243. In any case, if you really need to do this, just use  `urldecode` -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Try "decodeURI" instead of "decodeURIcomponent". I get the impression "key" is a string, not a component, but I could be wrong.

Comment: thanks titus that did it

Comment: is there anyway of undoing the encoding of the space? I'm guessing not, but I really wanted to replace the 20% with a space since that's the way the names are stored in my database

Comment: This code works for me `pathname.replace(/%20/g, ' ')`, but I assume there should be a more elegant way.